# AngularJS: Using $http.get to retrieve data and making it available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I am very new to AngularJS and want to get started retrieving data from a remote source.

My app.js file looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('footy', []);

app.controller('ClubController', ['$http', function($http){

    var club = this;
    club.team = [];

    $http.get('http://api.football-data.org/teams/19').success(function(data){
        club.team = data;
    });
}]);
```

and my html looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="footy">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div ng-controller = "ClubController as data">
    {{data.club.team.name}}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I view the page in a browser all that is returned is a blank page and in the source I can see "{{data.club.team.name}}" between the div.

When I view the data source Url in a browser I see this:

```
{

"id": 19,
"name": "Eintracht Frankfurt",
"shortName": "Eintr. Frankfurt",
"crestUrl": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/Eintracht_Frankfurt_Logo.svg"
}
```

I have gone through and completed this course: http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/ and was trying to apply the instructions from chapter 5 about services to this but I am having no luck.

Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<div ng-controller = "ClubController as data">` should be `<div ng-controller="ClubController as data">`

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: http://api.football-data.org/teams/19 doesn't allow CORS...

Comment: Well I think aarong gave the answer

Comment: @aarong looks like it does http://api.football-data.org/register i have an API key.

Comment: @404error ah...I stand corrected. See my answer for the other problem then.

Comment: @Mikey the console returns this XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.football-data.org/teams/19. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @404error if you're getting that error, you're encountering the same CORS issue I did. Are you sure you're using the API key correctly?

Comment: @aarong thanks for the help. I was missing one very important thing. You guys helped me with both. First i forgot to include this: {headers:{'X-Auth-Token':'my-key'}} after $http.get('http://api.football-data.org/teams/19', Second your answer about changing data.club.team.name to data.team.name was also something that needed fixing

Comment: @aarong how can i award you some karma for helping me?

Comment: @404error well...the generally accepted method is to mark the helpful answer accepted and continue to ask good questions/provide good answers when you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems here:

- http://api.football-data.org/teams/19 doesn't allow CORS. You can't load the data. **Update:** The OP pointed out that s/he has an API key that allows CORS. This is not the issue then, but might be for other people trying to reproduce this.
- `{{data.club.team.name}}` should be `{{data.team.name}}` because you said `var club = this;`. In other words, the controller you aliased `data` is the same as the `club` object. The `club` object is not a property of the controller data, it IS the controller's data.

See this plnkr for a demo. The commented out code doesn't work because of the api key, the locally hosted file does: http://plnkr.co/edit/ItD96Zfk0g1cLyGrrgBy?p=preview